# CubeMX doesn't create bluenrg_utils.c

Tags: stm32, bluetooth, stm32cubemx

In case someone already stumbled upon this issue I'd be glad about every advice.
So I have an STM32 that is connected to a BlueNRG-MS and I set everything up using the CubeMX. There I select the `X-CUBE-BLE` under `Additional Software` and generate my code.

In general everything works fine but now I'd like to change the default IFR configuration.
My problem now is that in my project I do have a `bluenrg_utils.h` which holds all the required function declarations such as

`void change_IFR_data_config(IFR_config2_TypeDef *IFR_config, uint8_t data[64]);`

but it seems like CubeMX only generates a `bluenrg_utils_small.c` where all the required implementations are missing (only what is already used in the STM example is implemented).
I can find `bluenrg_utils.c` in the web (e.g. [here](https://github.com/stm32duino/SPBTLE-RF/blob/master/src/STM32_BlueNRG/SimpleBlueNRG_HCI/hci/controller/bluenrg_utils.c)) but I'd like to understand why CubeMX doesn't generate this file in the first place.

Comment: Did you try Copy & Paste solution?

Comment: You mean to copy the file into my project? Or copy its content into `bluenrg_utils_small.c`?

Comment: CubeMX  and mentioned project (or some other)  are two different things. The names bluenrg_utils_small.c and bluenrg_utils.c may seem very close, but this is just a case. You would need to copy entire project, or at least find the differences.

Comment: Sorry, differences between what?